# How to find the bound of a time dependent variable?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics, bounds, range

I am working on modeling my problem statistically and I need to Know the bound or range of my variable. It is a time series variable position(t) where

position(t+1) = position(t) + a.X - (1-a).Y

a is a variable uniformly sampled between 0 and 1. X and Y are other variables that are given. I want to know the range position at all times that is what are the bounds of it in terms of X and Y.

Comment: What about $b$? Is it random or fixed/known? Does $a$ have a distribution or fixed/known? I'm struggling to see the statistical aspect of this question

Comment: @jcken sorry I just updated the qustion. I have differt venhicles and for each vehicle I calculate its position at each time step. Each vehicle has a unique "a" that is sampled uniformly between 0 and 1.

Comment: you say you have different vehicles? Do you have one time series for each vehicle? If so, is $a$ drawn at every one time interval or just once for each vehicle?

Comment: @Dayne at every time interval;

Comment: @Dayne yes I have one time series for each vehicle and a is drawn at each time interval.

Answer (score 1):

Here I assume $X, Y >0$ and are fixed. We know $a \sim U(0,1)$.  Also, if $k>0$ then $a  k \sim U(0, k)$. Further, $ak + r \sim U(r, k+r)$. Denote the position at time $t$ by $p(t)$.

Now define $z = aX - (1-a)Y$.  Here $z$ is a random variable. We can re-write $z = a(X+Y) - Y \sim U(-Y, X)$. This means that the position from time $t$ to time $t+1$ changes by an amount somewhere in the range $(-Y, X)$ and each value in this range is equally likely. Therefore, we have $p(t+1) \in (p(t)-Y, p(t) + X)$. Further, $p(t+1) \mid p(t) \sim U(p(t)-Y, p(t) + X)$.

Finally, as @Dayne said, the distribution for $p(t)$ is [Irwin-Hall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution). If $p(0)$ is the initial position then the time $t$ position is in the range $(p(0)-tY, p(0)+ tX)$. If the position is know at time $t' > 0$ we can reduce the width of the interval to $\left(p(0) -(t-t')Y, p(0)+(t - t')X \right)$.

Comment: two things: (1) shouldn't $z \sim U(-Y,X)$? (2) At time $t$ an obvious extension from conditional distribution to marginal is easy. Bound should be initial position + $t(-Y) to tX$ and the distribution of $p(t)$ will be irving-hall.

Comment: @Dayne - corrected. I'd never come across Irwin-Hall before, thanks for bringing it up